# Proving that $1, z, \ldots, z^m$ is linearly independent in $P_m (F)$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove that for any $m \geq 0$, the list of monomials $1, z, \ldots, z^m$ is linearly independent in $P_m (F)$, the vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $m$.

My first attempt was to follow the definition, so we suppose that for $a_0, \ldots, a_{m+1} \in F$, we have
$$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^m a_i z^i = 0. 
$$
At this point I want to say, "equating coefficients, we have $a_i = 0$ for all $i$." As a polynomial is uniquely determined by its coefficients, and I have polynomials on both the left- and right-side, I believe I'm able to do this. I also only have one monomial of each degree on the left-hand side. I'm not certain that this argument works, however, or that I'm even using the fact that these are carefully chosen monomials.

Does this argument work?

Comment: What is your definition of the polynomial ring $F[x]$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Axler doesn't define $F[x]$, but an element $p(x) \in P(F)$ is defined as a function from $F$ to $F$ of the form $\sum\limits_{i=0}^m a_i x^i$ for $a_i \in F$.

Comment: Sigh, one should not identify polynomials and polynomial functions. For example for $F=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ the polynomial functions $x, x^2, \dots, x^m$ from $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ to itself are all the same and so they are not linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. So, with your definition, the claim is simply false.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Oh, sorry, that's true. Axler also declares that $F = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. With that definition, does the argument work? I know that some of these results fail for fields of characteristic $2$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, in that case it is true as the polynomial functions and the usual polynomials can be identified.

Comment: Over rings with infinitely many elements, the two notions coincide. If you have seen that those are the same notions, then you can indeed just compare coefficients. Otherwise, you need to resort to other tools. You could for example differentiate the equation $m$ times and get $$ a_m \cdot m! =0 $$ and hence $a_m=0$. Then you differentiate the equation just $m-1$ times and get (we already know $a_m=0$) $$ a_{m-1} (m-1)! =0 $$ and so $a_{m-1}=0$ and so on.

Comment: Please note that the statement fails for all finite fields $F$. This can be seen by a simple counting argument. There are $\vert F \vert^2$ maps from $F$ to itself. So if you pick $m=\vert F \vert^2$, then some of the $m+1$ polynomial functions $1, z, \dots, z^m$ must coincide and in particular the family is not linearly independent over $F$.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :) I realized that I should formulate this as an answer. People seem to get upset if questions are answered in the comments (got this complaint already once today).

Comment: The argument in the question looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over rings with infinitely many elements, the notion of polynomials and polynomial functions can be identified. If you have seen that those are the same notions, then you can indeed just compare coefficients. Otherwise, you need to resort to other tools. You could for example differentiate the equation $m$ times and get $$ a_m \cdot m! =0 $$ and hence $a_m=0$. Then you differentiate the equation just $m-1$ times and get (we already know $a_m=0$) $$ a_{m-1} (m-1)! =0 $$ and so $a_{m-1}=0$ and so on.

Please note that the statement fails for all finite fields $F$ (the issue is not really characteristic $2$). This can be seen by a simple counting argument. There are $\vert F \vert^2$ maps from $F$ to itself. So if you pick $m=\vert F \vert^2$, then some of the $m+1$ polynomial functions $1, z, \dots, z^m$ must coincide and in particular the family is not linearly independent over $F$.

For the identification of polynomials and polynomial functions over an infinite field $K$. Consider the map

$$ \varphi: K[x] \rightarrow \{ f: K \rightarrow K \ \vert \ \exists g\in K[x] \forall k\in K : f(k) = g(k)  \}, g \mapsto (k \mapsto g(k)). $$

By construction $\varphi$ is surjective. It is easy to check that $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism. We are left to check that $\varphi$ is injective. For this we only need to show that the kernel of $\varphi$ is just the zero polynomial.

Let $f(x)\in \text{Ker}(\varphi) \setminus \{0\}$. Pick $k_1\in K$, we have $f(k_1)=0$ and therefore there exists a polynomial $f_1(x)$ such that $f(x) = (x-k_1) f_1(x)$. Now if we pick another element $k_2\in K$, then we get $0=f(k_2) = (k_2-k_2) f_1(k_2)$ and so $f_1(k_2)=0$ (as we are in a field). Thus, we can write $f(x) = (x-k_1)(x-k_2) f_2(x)$. In particular, this argument gives you that if $f$ has $m$ zeros, then $\text{deg}(f(x))\geq m$. However, $f(x)$ vanishes for all elements in $K$, which implies that it would need to have infinite degree which yields a contradiction (of course the very same argument could be run in an infinite integral domain and we would get the same result).

Comment: More precisely, in the finite field $\mathbb F_q$, every element equals its own $q$-th power: $x=x^q$. However, I would never identify polynomials with polynomial functions, and certainly call the polynomial $z^q$ different (indeed linearly independent from) the polynomial $z$, over any field.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Absolutely! Your argument is much nicer. You might wish to make that an answer too.

Comment: By the way, the differentiation argument fails over finite fields as well, actually over any positive characteristic field as soon as $m \ge char(K)$. Because then $m! = 0$ in $K$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Sure, this was meant to only cover $K\in \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$, otherwise I would have called it formal differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you see $z$. In your case your Ring can be seen as $F[z]/<z^{m+1}-1>$. Now if $$p(z) = \sum_{i=0}^m a_i z^i = 0 \implies F[z]/<z^{m+1}-1> = F[z]/<z^{m+1}-1,p(z)> $$ $$ \implies <z^{m+1}-1> =  <z^{m+1}-1,p(z)>$$ i.e., the ideal generated by $z^{m+1}-1$ is same as ideal generated by $z^{m+1}-1,p(z)$. But if $F$ is a PID, then $<z^{m+1}-1,p(z)> = <d(z)>$ where $d(z) = gcd(z^{m+1}-1,p(z))$. Hence degree of $d(z) <$ $m+1$ . Hence $<z^{m+1}-1> = <d(z)>$. But then this means $d(z) \in <z^{m+1}-1>$. Hence $z^{m+1}-1$ divided $d(z)$. But then degree of $d(z)$ < $m+1$ which is impossible. Hence $p(z) = $ zero polynomial with $a_i = 0$ or $p(z)$ is a multiple of $z^{m+1}-1$. But degree of $p(z)$ is $< m+1$. Hence $p(z) = 0$ polynomial and $a_i = 0$.

So for your statement to hold its enough to have $F$ as a PID (Principal Ideal Domain).

The above is in the view that $z$ is transcendental in $F[z]$. But then if you view $p(z) = \sum_{i=0}^m a_i z^i = 0$ as $p(r) = 0, \forall r \in F$ then this is linear algebra. Form $m+1$ equations $p(r_1) = p(r_2) = ... = p(r_{m+1}) = 0$ and this can be written as $V\underline{a} = 0$ where $V$ is vandermonde matrix and is non-singular if $m+1$ elements are distinct then the equation $V\underline{a} = 0 \implies \underline{a}=0$. So in this viewpoint, if $F$ has $m+1$ distinct elements then $p(z) = 0 \implies a_i = 0$. Note that if $F$ has < $m+1$ elements, it could happen that $p(z) = 0$ but $a_i \neq 0$. Example $p(z) = z(z-1)$ over $F = \{0,1\}$. clearly $p(0) = p(1) = 0$ but coefficients $a_i \neq 0$.

Good Luck !

Comment: I strongly believe that identifying the plain old subspace of polynomials of degree $\le m$ with this quotient ring of the full polynomial ring does not help OP or clarify what is going on. The multiplicative structure (beyond scalar multiplication) is totally redundant here and just adds complication in notation and arguments.

Comment: I felt $1,z,z^2,...,z^i$ inherently starts a multiplicative structure. So i used quotient space. Anyway thanks for the comment. Interesting to see how you will escape multiplicative structure.

Comment: The question is about a vector space. There is no multiplication (beyond scalar multiplication) on it. That's an easy escape.